# Dynamic entry template not loading on staging site but works on local.dev

Tags: templating, routes

I'm having a strange issue where pages aren't loading on the staging site that were all working fine on the local.dev site.

I have a Section called **Available Homes** and in that section it has two Entry types called **Available Homes** and **Plot** which link to two entry templates, that are dynamically called from the main entry.html.twig template, which then links to the sub folder

```
/entry
  /availablehomes
    availablehomes.html.twig
    plot.html.twig
  default.html.twig
```

The sections Entry URL Format is as follows:

`developments/{counties.first.slug}/{developments.first.slug}/available-homes`

and nested entries get the following:

`{parent.uri}/{slug}`

If I change the template from entry in the control panel to different template then it loads.

This is the entry template code:

```
{% include [
  "entry/" ~ entry.section.handle ~ "/" ~ entry.type,
  "entry/default"
] %}
```

Can someone help please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing staging has a case sensitive file system and your local dev site doesn't.

i.e. the section handle in your screenshot is called `availableHomes`, but the template folder you're referencing is `availablehomes`.

Comment: Amazing, that was it. Something so simple. Will be extra careful with the folder naming in future. Thanks